# c++ return *this, how to think it

Tags: c++

When I searched for `return *this`, I found someone explaining it as a chained assignment function.
[image]

But when I follow the blogger's implementation, I found that this is not the case.
[image: return *this]
[image: //return *this]

Though one has the code `return *this`, the other has not, the two results is same.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Wd {
private:
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    Wd &operator=(Wd const &as) {
        this->a = as.a;
        this->b = as.b;
        return *this;
    };
};

int main() {
    Wd a;
    a.b =3;
    a.a =4;
    Wd c,b,d;
    d.a=6;
    d=c=b=a;
    cout<<d.a<<a.a<<b.a<<c.a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not returning any value from a function expecting a return value is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). There are no language standard guarantees on what should happen. So anything could. The comparison therefore is not fair. Relying on UB is bad.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3):

Semantic of assignment expression like `a=b` is :

- first, set the value of `a` to the value of `b`,
- second, the value of the whole expression is the value of `a` after assignment. `a=b=c` is equivalent to `a = (b=c)`.

As `a=b` is `a.operator=(b)`, the return value of the operator must be the value of `a` after assignment, thus the following is the most common way of implementing it:

```
K &operator=(const K &arg) {
    // code to assign this with values in arg
    return *this; // return the current assigned object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this

```
class Wd{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    Wd &operator =(Wd const &as){
        this->a = as.a;
        this->b = as.b;
        return *this;
    };
};
```

creates an object with only one function `operator=`.

That function is defined as returning a reference to the invoking object.

```
    return *this;
```

says 'return what the this object points at'. `this` points at the current Wd instance. If the retrun type we `Wd` then it would retunr a copy, but becuase the return type is `Wd&` it returns a reference to it, this is effectively a pointer

so now look at the main code

```
        Wd a;
        a.b =3;
        a.a =4;
```

first we create a Wd and initialize its members.

Then we do (simplified a bit)

```
        Wd c;
        Wd d;
        d = c = a;
```

`d = c= a` translates to

```
       d.operator=(c.operator=(a))
```

and because `c.operator=(a)` returns a reference to a this is equivalent to

```
      d.operator=(a)
```

One of the main reason for the existance of references is to permit chaining like this. The most well known one is this

```
     cout << x << " " << y << "!!" << z;
```

this works because `operator<<` for streams is defined as returning a reference to its invoking stream.

Comment: Thanks,With your explaination ,And  coding  the source code of auto_ptr by myself,I gradually configure it out.

Comment: @Parsifal coding `auto_ptr`??? Don't! `auto_ptr` is a failure and has been removed from the language since C++17! What tutorial are you using??? Get a newer one.

Comment: I'm studying c++11,and I want to make unique_ptr ,weak_ptr,shared_ptr and auto_ptr.